# Modprobe and insmod

Tags: drivers, kernel, modprobe

I was trying to install the rt8188eu drivers for my USB adapter and while trying to enable the module which I cloned from git, through modprobe `sudo modprobe 8188eu` it was throwing me a exec format error. While doing `insmod 8188eu.ko`successfully installed the module and my device is working perfectly.. Could anybody point out to me the differences between the two commands

Comment: After the git clone, did you compile the software yourself, on your current kernel, or did you use an included binary file of 8188eu.ko? Tell me the link for the git software you downloaded,

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git

Comment: i compiled it myself using ` make ` and ` make install ` and then ` modprobe 8188eu ` failed while ` insmod 8188eu.ko ` worked perfectly

Comment: Did you execute `depmod -a` after `make install`?

Comment: You should have done a `make all` and a `sudo make install`... or better yet, followed the instructions for a dkms install. I would `sudo make uninstall` and then do the dkms install.